# Working of a Polarizer

Tags: homework-and-exercises, polarization

If a Polarizer only allow Electric Field to travel in one direction . How does perpendicular magnetic field get pass through a polarizer?

Comment: By convention, the "polarization" of electromagnetic waves refers to the direction of the electric field.

Answer (score 0):

every electric field has magnetic field associated with it, there are many orientations of electric fields and every electric field has its corresponding magnetic field. in polarization electric fields are blocked by allowing to pass electric field in only one orientation and thus when electric field pass through polarizer, changing(oscillating) electric field produce magnetic field perpendicular to it.magnetic field actually not pass through the polarizer but it is produced as a result of changing electric field.magnetic field is produced after electric field is passed through slit so magnetic field has nothing to do with slit in this case.